# how to create a HTML object in to .html file in R

Tags: html, r

I have an html object as follows,

```
library(R2HTML)
heading <- c(
"<html>
 <head>
 <body>
 <p> A new program </p></br>
 </br>
 </body>
 </html>")
```

I need to create this in to a `.html` file. Till now I have tried

```
writeLines(text=           
"<html>
 <head>
 <body>
 <p>A new program</p>
 </br>
 </br>      
 </body>
 </html>",
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
```

But this creates a `.html` in the `tempdir()` but I need to this created at `setwd()`. How do I do this ?

Comment: Doing a variable assignment like that within the call to `writeLines` may seem a shortcut but it's pretty bad form and likely to cause confusion later on down the road (and saves neither memory or CPU cycles). `tf <- tempfile(tmpdir=setwd("."), fileext=".html"); writeLines("somelongmultilinehtmltext", tf)` will do what you need.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you for the reply. Will try it and keep u posted.

Comment: writeLines(text=           
             "<html>
           <head>
           <body>
           <p> A new program  </p></br>
           
           </br>      
           </body>
           </html>",
   ".html")    Is this what you want?